# Get Facebook page post ID from URL for Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

how can I get the post ID from the URL?

I need to update the Facebook page post, and I need for that post ID.
Problem is, that I have only the post URL.

What I need to do with Facebook API:
https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/POST_ID/?message=NEW_TEXT3&access_token=MY_TOKEN

What I have (eaxmple):
https://www.facebook.com/mypage/posts/pfbid12345/

Maybe there is some tool or Facebook API for that?
I try to use "pfbid12345" as post ID, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Post id may not be available in the url if post has multiple images then URL will refer to media in the post and not the actual post.

However, Facebook follows some format for post id - `<page_id>_<post_id>`, so in your case, you can try `<mypage post id>_pfbid12345` and try to update post.

If you've permission to update the post then you should use fetch page post API to fetch post data and use post id from the same, you must not use id from url for performing action.